# Dynamically return a class constructor in TypeScript

Tags: javascript, typescript, factory

I'm trying to build a mechanism in TypeScript to return a new instance of a class based on a string parameter representing the name of the class. Basically, I'm trying to create a factory, only I can't quite figure out how to do this in TypeScript. In pure JS, I could get away with this by just storing all the class constructors in a key/value object and calling `new ClassDictionary[className]();` - it's not the most robust solution, but it works in this situation. I can't seem to get the right combination of types and casting to accomplish this in TypeScript. Is there a better way? I haven't been able to find any examples of factory pattern in TypeScript, so right now I've just got a bit switch statement, which is ugly and inflexible.

Comment: sounds like a builder pattern. [this might help](https://github.com/torokmark/design_patterns_in_typescript/blob/master/builder/builder.ts)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can add a function declaration for every class in the dictionary, this can looks like this (Visit: https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/declaration-merging.html):

```
class MyClass { 
    myMethod() { return "my return"; }
}

function factory(className: "Date"): Date;
function factory(className: "Number"): Number;
function factory(className: "MyClass"): MyClass;
function factory(className: string) { 

    var ClassDictionary = {
        "Date": Date,
        "Number": Number,
        "MyClass": MyClass
    };

    return new ClassDictionary[className]();
}

var d = factory("Date");

/* Its a date. */
alert(d.toISOString());

var n = factory("Number");

/* Now a number. */
alert(n.toPrecision());

var c = factory("MyClass");

/* And now MyClass. */
alert(c.myMethod());
```

Works in the Playground ([Sample](http://www.typescriptlang.org/Playground#src=class%20MyClass%20%7B%20%0A%09myMethod%28%29%20%7B%20return%20%22my%20return%22%3B%20%7D%0A%7D%0A%0Afunction%20factory%28className%3A%20%22Date%22%29%3A%20Date%3B%0Afunction%20factory%28className%3A%20%22Number%22%29%3A%20Number%3B%0Afunction%20factory%28className%3A%20%22MyClass%22%29%3A%20MyClass%3B%0Afunction%20factory%28className%3A%20string%29%20%7B%20%0A%09%0A%09var%20ClassDictionary%20%3D%20%7B%0A%09%09%22Date%22%3A%20Date%2C%0A%09%09%22Number%22%3A%20Number%2C%0A%09%09%22MyClass%22%3A%20MyClass%0A%09%7D%3B%0A%09%0A%09return%20new%20ClassDictionary[className]%28%29%3B%0A%7D%0A%0Avar%20d%20%3D%20factory%28%22Date%22%29%3B%0A%0A%2F*%20Its%20a%20date.%20*%2F%0Aalert%28d.toISOString%28%29%29%3B%0A%0Avar%20n%20%3D%20factory%28%22Number%22%29%3B%0A%0A%2F*%20Now%20a%20number.%20*%2F%0Aalert%28n.toPrecision%28%29%29%3B%0A%0Avar%20c%20%3D%20factory%28%22MyClass%22%29%3B%0A%0A%2F*%20And%20now%20MyClass.%20*%2F%0Aalert%28c.myMethod%28%29%29%3B))

Or in a other way

```
// ...
var ClassDictionary = { };

ClassDictionary["Date"] = Date;
function factory(className: "Date"): Date;

ClassDictionary["Number"] = Number;
function factory(className: "Number"): Number;

ClassDictionary["MyClass"] = MyClass;
function factory(className: "MyClass"): MyClass;

function factory(className: string) { 
    return new ClassDictionary[className]();
}
// ...
```

Or with Arguments:

```
class MyClass {
    constructor(public myReturn: string) { }
    myMethod() { return this.myReturn; }
}

var ClassDictionary = { };

ClassDictionary["Date"] = Date;
function factory(className: "Date"): Date;

ClassDictionary["Number"] = Number;
function factory(className: "Number", value?: number): Number;

ClassDictionary["MyClass"] = MyClass;
function factory(className: "MyClass", myReturn: string): MyClass;

function factory(className: string, valueOrMyReturn?: number | string) { 
   if(valueOrMyReturn) return new ClassDictionary[className](valueOrMyReturn);
    return new ClassDictionary[className]();
}

var d = factory("Date");

/* Its a date. */
alert(d.toISOString());

var n = factory("Number", 42);

/* Now a number. */
alert(n.toPrecision());

var c = factory("MyClass", "This is the answer!");

/* And now MyClass. */
alert(c.myMethod());
```

Comment: This did the trick for what I needed. I created a simple Factory class with a static dictionary of class references. Since all my classes inherit from the same base, I only needed one function signature. Simple and effective, thanks for the idea!

Answer (score 1):

Let's imagine that you have a class definition:

```
module UI
{
    export class MyClass
    {
        constructor( data: any )
        {}
     }
}
```

You can use this kind of construction:

```
public static CreateController(  data: IControllerData ): any
    {
        return new data.namespace[data.controller]( data.initializationData );
    }
```

where data is JS object and is something like this:

```
var data = {
            namespace: UI,
            controller: "MyClass"// <- this is the class name
            initializationData: {} // this is the parameters that you want to pass in constructor
}
```

to create new instace of the MyClass class.